# Filter datagrid view - recordset

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, recordset

I am trying to have a button on my project that will filter my datagridview, by selecting the operator and then in a text box enter the value. I am using Vb.net, Access and ado

I have some code here, but I think it is wrong, it does not say it is something wrong, but when I run then it gives me an error message.

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGo.Click
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim s As String, sErro As String
        Dim retval As Boolean
        sErro = ""
        s = "select " & comboField.SelectedItem & " from " & Me.tbName
        retval = getRS(s, rs, False, sErro)
        If retval Then
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

                If comboOperador.SelectedItem = "~" Then

                    If rs.Fields(i).Value Like txtVal.Text Then
                        rs.Filter= rs.Fields(i).Value & " Like '*" & txtVal.Text & "*'"
                    End If

                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

I also believe this is wrong

```
s = "select " & comboField.SelectedItem & " from " & Me.tbName
```

Because it is not going throught the whole row. Only getting the first one.

Any help I would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message please.

Comment: @HereGoes "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.'"

Comment: @HereGoes I changed a little bit...then I got another error "'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LINQ.  Once you have your datatable...

```
    Dim Query = From row In yourDataTable
       Where row.Item(i) Like "*" & txtVal.Text & "*" 
       Select row.Item(i)
```

You can then loop through the Query Result...

```
    For Each TheResult In Query
        MsgBox(TheResult)
    Next
```

As for the s = "select " & comboField.SelectedItem & " from " & Me.tbName try the SelectedValue property instead of the SelectedItem.